# Angular CLI + Angular2-JWT Error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-jwt

1. I used Angular CLI to generate an app.
2. Ran "npm install angular2-jwt" in the terminal
3. Added the script reference to angular-cli.json:

   ```
   "scripts":[
      ...
        "../node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js"
      ...
    ]
   ```
4. Ran "ng serve" No problems so far
5. But if I browse to http://localhost:4200 I get:

```
    caught ReferenceError: require is not defined at scripts.bundle.js:224 (anonymous) @ scripts.bundle.js:224
```

[image]

I don't want to keep implementing angular2-JWT with this error around.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer, and actually there's an [issue](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/372) open at Github about this, unresolved.

So i found [this manual implementation of JWT authentication for the client](https://github.com/jamesboh/angular4-cli-jwt-authentication-example)

The idea is just to retrieve the token from the server, store it in the local storage, and then send it as a header in each request.